# MySQL Query - Lowest Values with Multiple Tables / Joins

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

i am requesting some help for a query to be used on a custom golf website.

what i need is to find the lowest score per player per course. my club has 3 nine hole loops, 27 holes in total, but i want to find the lowest per 9 holes (i.e. course as i am describing it).

i have the following database structure (note, i haven’t put in all rows, only those that are pertinent to the query i am stuggling with).

[Golf DB ERP Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rk5AA.jpg)

a query to get the full set of data would be (note some field names are different - the diagram was trying to better descriptive…):

```
select * from round r, round_hole rh, player p, course_nine c, course_hole ch 
where r.r_id = rh.rh_rid 
and p.id = r.r_pid 
and c.cn_nine = r.r_nine 
and ch.ch_nine = c.cn_nine 
and rh.rh_hid = ch.ch_no
```

a snapshot of the results are:

[Full query ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v353N.png)

however, i then need to filter it as above, into "per player, per  course”

i am presuming this is some subquery, join, temp table or “in” type statement, but struggling, particularly as it spans multiple tables.

any help is appreciated

Comment: Please learn how to use proper explicit `join` syntax.

Comment: Are you still working to figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished using some simple aggregation. As long as you are able to properly join all of your tables, you can do this:

```
SELECT player, course, MIN(score) AS lowestScore
FROM myTables
GROUP BY player, course;
```

Comment: thanks for the hint. didn't realise the multiple group by's could be used.

the final query is used was:

select sub_nine, sum(sub.sub_low_nett) as points, sub_pid from
(
select c.cn_nine as sub_nine, min(rh.rh_nett) as sub_low_nett, p.id as sub_pid
from round r, round_hole rh, player p, course_nine c, course_hole ch 
where r.r_id = rh.rh_rid 
and p.id = r.r_pid 
and c.cn_nine = r.r_nine 
and ch.ch_nine = c.cn_nine 
and rh.rh_hid = ch.ch_no 
group by p.id, c.cn_nine, ch.ch_no
) as sub
group by sub_pid